# HTTP based "mirror"

Tags: powershell

I am looking to implement a PS based system to manage a local library of assets, specifically a library of Revit Family files. There is a "vetted library" that acts as the source library, to which items can be added, removed or revised. This library then needs to be mirrored on the local machine.

I do this now with the vetted library on the network, and I do a Robocopy /mir at every user logon. This works great for a traditional office environment with laptops that sometimes leave the office, to ensure they have the current library. However, with Work From Home now a major issue, I want to implement a similar functionality but with a web hosted library, either on my own server or an Amazon S3 bucket. My thinking is to make this a two stage process.
1: At update of the vetted library, an XML file is updated, which includes the entire folder structure and file data for the library, including file size and file hash.
2: On the local machine, I download the vetted library map, and compare with the previous map. Missing and extraneous files are easy, though moved files are a bit more complex. Files with different sizes are easy too. If files are the same size, then already computed hashes are compared. In this way I can build a list of files to be deleted locally, as well as new files to be downloaded.
These libraries can easily reach 5gb and 10k files per library, and every year a new library is required. Often firms have as many as 5 year versions of the software installed. So, LOTS of files and lots of size.

This seems like the most performant way to handle regular updates, but I wonder if there is a cmdlet already available that handles this kind of thing better?

I know I COULD do this with Dropbox or the like, but there are a number of arguments against it, from the size of the libraries to security and access control (which I will need to address with my solution eventually as well). These libraries can cost 10s of thousands of $ to purchase, and folks aren't going to want to manage them via dropbox or OneDrive.

And... the fact that Microsoft has OneDrive has me thinking there isn't a built in PS way to do this, since they want to push OneDrive. In which case, is my file map compare based approach viable, or is there a better approach I should consider.

I know there is no code here, so maybe I am running afoul of some Stack overflow rule, but hopefully program specification and planning is seen as an appropriate avenue for questions as well as simple code solutions.